# Pyplot zorder lost with animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, z-order

I am trying to animate different objects in the same graph using pyplot's funcanimation.
It works almost as I expect it to, except for the order in which the different elements are displayed in. So the plot curve, text and legend are shown behind the image where they are barely seen.

Here is my (not so) minimal working example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random

def init():
    line_simu.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    imobj.set_data(np.zeros((100, 100)))
    imobj.set_zorder(0)
    time_text.set_zorder(10)
    return line_simu,  time_text, imobj

def animate(i):
    imobj.set_zorder(0)
    time_text.set_zorder(10)
    y_simu = np.linspace(0,100, 100)
    x_simu =    np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) 
    line_simu.set_data(x_simu, y_simu)

    time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' % i )

    global data
    imobj.set_data( data + np.random.random((100,1)) * 0.5 )

    return line_simu, time_text, imobj


def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-15,15), ylim=(-110, 0) , aspect=1)

data = np.random.random((100,100)) - .5
imobj = ax.imshow( data , extent=[-15,15, -110, 0.0], origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=-2, vmax=2, alpha=.7, zorder=0, aspect=1)

line_simu, = ax.plot([], [],"r--", lw=2, markersize=4 , label = "Some curve" ,  zorder= 2 )

time_text = ax.text(-14.9, -108, '', zorder=10)

l = plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size':8} )
l.set_zorder(200)

forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,  frames=range( 50), interval=3000, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Without animation, I can easily control the order of the different elements with set_zorder, but when the animation updates the image, this order is lost. I tried to set the zorder in the init function and again in the animate function, without success.

I am very thankful for any help on that matter.

Comment: I notice that the `line_sumu` you are updating in this example does not exist inside the axes extent, so it doesn't show no matter what the zorder is.  But if I fix that, this actually works fine for me without any zorder issues, using 1.3.1.  What version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: Thank you Ajean. I edited the problem with the line outside the bounds, but it was merely to illustrate. It is good news that it worked for you, I have indeed an older version: 1.1.1. I'll try to update it and I'll let you know.

Comment: Finally, I got a chance to test the script with matplotlib 1.3.1. Unfortunately it does not solve anything. You only can see the curve/legend/timestring through transparence, the image remains on top and deteriorate the readability of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: It seems that the order in witch the init() and animate() functions return objects controls the order in which they are displayed. Additionally those functions should return the legend object in order to include it in the animation.

Here is my corrected code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random

def init():
    imobj.set_data(np.zeros((100, 100)))
    line_simu.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('time = 0.0')

    return imobj , line_simu,  time_text,  l

def animate(i):
    global data
    imobj.set_data( data + np.random.random((100,1)) * 0.5 )

    imobj.set_zorder(0)
    y_simu = np.linspace(-100,-10, 100)
    x_simu = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) 
    line_simu.set_data(x_simu, y_simu)
    time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' % i )


    return imobj , line_simu, time_text,  l


def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-15,15), ylim=(-110, 0) , aspect=1)

data = np.random.random((100,100)) - .5
imobj = ax.imshow( data , extent=[-15,15, -110, 0.0], origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=-2, vmax=2, alpha=1.0, zorder=1, aspect=1)

line_simu, = ax.plot([], [],"r--", lw=2, markersize=4 , label = "Some curve" ,  zorder= 1 )
time_text = ax.text(-14.0, -108, '', zorder=10)

forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)

l = plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop={'size':8} )

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,  frames=range( 50), interval=500, blit=True)

plt.show()
```